# Laravel with Docker issue connecting MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, docker, laravel-5, docker-compose

Steps I follow to setup Laravel using Docker: in my local system I don't have  installed PHP, Composer, Apache, MySQL, phpMyAdmin, etc. I only have Git and Docker install in my system.

1. git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
2. create docker-composer.yml file on project root.

   ```
   version: "3"
   services:
     db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
       MYSQL_DATABASE: db
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"

   web:
     image: php:7.2.2-apache
     container_name: web_laravel
     depends_on:
       - db
     volumes:
       - ./:/var/www/html/
     ports:
       - "4000:80"
     stdin_open: true
     tty: true

   phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     depends_on:
       - db
     external_links:
       - db:mysql
     ports:
       - "9191:80"
     environment:
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
       PMA_HOST: db
   ```
3. run command from project root.

   ```
   docker-compose up
   ```

   This command will fetch all the images (php:7.2.2-apache, phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin, mysql:5.7) from local cache or Docker Hub and start three containers for these images.

   Now I need to interact with php:7.2.2-apache image's container called web_laravel (see in yml file) so I can add PHP extensions and Composer to run Laravel project.
4. run this command.

   ```
   docker exec -it web_laravel /bin/bash
   ```

   Now I have access to run any command in running web_laravel container so I've installed Composer and PHP extensions like mbstrings, pdo, pdo_mysql etc.

   Then install Laravel dependency using composer install, set permission for storage and bootstrap/cache folders and run php artisan key:generate.

   open localhost:4000 and I'm able to see Laravel home page:

   [image]

At this point all is good. The problem starts now when I'm connecting to my DB.

Next command to run (I'm still within container):

```
  php artisan migrate
```

and the errors are:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)

 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)
```

[image]

[image]

I'm able to open phpMyAdmin (**http://localhost:9191**) and can create DB, table and operations related DB. I've DB called **blog**.

MySQL env variables:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036471/laravel-fails-to-connect-to-database-while-in-docker-container/59037259#59037259

Answer (score 6):

try DB_HOST=host.docker.internal

---

Inside `docker-compose.yml`

```
 environment:
      - DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
```

Works also.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this does not work in Linux

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a couple of issues, the first is that laravel .env configuration should point to the MySQL container, not localhost

`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

should be

`DB_HOST=db`

And the other error you talked about, is not related to Docker

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
>   file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where
>   table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and
>   table_name = migrations)

it's probably related to a missing dependency, you should run

`composer require doctrine/dbal`

Also, you said:

> now I have access to run any command in running web_laravel container
>   so I've installed composer and php extensions like mbstrings, pdo,
>   pdo_mysql etc.

You should build your image on top of PHP 7/Apache image, and add those to the build dockerfile, because your changes (php extensions, configurations...etc) are not persistent. I would suggest you use [Laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock) or any other existing Laravel/docker environment.

Comment: still not working.I don't want to use Laradock. I want to create my own dev environment. Your suggestion is good feedback to build your image on top of PHP 7/Apache.

Comment: I'm not able to connect with mysql and same error show.

Comment: I would debug it further, isolate the 2 issues, you can install mysql-cli on PHP container, and try connecting from there, using mysql -h db -u root -p 
if it works, then connecting the two containers is good to go,
but the laravel dependency issue is left. or you can grab a zipped version of phpmyadmin into PHP container, and see if it connects to MySQL container.

I think you issue is the laravel dependency, you can try creating a table manually from PHPMyAdmin,like users table,and running any UserModel::all() on it, to see if it pulls data, then the issue is when running migrations only

Comment: Changing DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 to DB_HOST=db worked to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my Docker-compose.yml, I added this:

```
phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin'
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            PMA_HOST: mysql
        networks:
            - sail
```

In my Laravel Env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=teram_a_notificationdemo
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

You have to change DB_HOST=mysql to DB_HOST=127.0.0.1