# Laravel 8 migration works, but MySQL Refuses Connection

Tags: php, mysql, docker, laravel-8

I have a laravel project setup with docker (I currently run it using docker-compose). The project was working fine yesterday but it has stopped functioning **partially** today.
The most amazing thing is that although `migrations` and `seeders` work just fine, I can't fetch any result from the database! I've tried clearing caches and every other guide I could find but they didn't work at all.
My file contents are:

#### .env

```
APP_NAME=bookshelf
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:/PqZs+/8YfRYtCth0U5LATD5oOXCN/5pdAs5onk1z7U=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://0.0.0.0:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    image: $COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
    container_name: $COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME-laravel
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: $COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME-mysql
    ports:
    - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: 'mysql'
    ports:
    - '127.0.0.1:8080:80'
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_mysql \
        zip
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

As I said, the following commands work totally ok:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
```

But when I want to load a page with the following `Controller@method`:

```
public function index()
{
    $records = Book::all();
...
```

which fetches results from `books` table, I get the following error in the corresponding page/url/route:

[image]

So... I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. For some reason, my MySQL `.env` config worked fine yesterday but I had to set the `DB_HOST` to `mysql` which is the name of the service, created in `docker-compose.yml`; so, after changing it:

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  ...

  mysql: # <- I copied this name
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: $COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME-mysql
    ports:
    - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
  ...
```

#### .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql # <- pasted it here
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53921768/14588867) and as I tried it, it worked!
I'm gonna leave this Q&A for anyone else who might have such an ambiguous problem.

EDIT:
Strangely enough, after doing so, `migrate` command has stopped working.
I am currently oscillating between `DB_HOST=0.0.0.0` for `migrations` and `seeding` and `DB_HOST=mysql` for other purposes throughout the application...
If anyone got a solution for this, let me know

Comment: Yes, when you deal with docker, your service IP should be the docker service name. Docker uses internal networking to communicate with multiple containers defined in your `docker-compose.yml`. So, if next time you want to use another service, maybe `redis`, then in your `.env` the host should be `redis` or whichever service name you give to your redis container.

Comment: I see, it still doesn't answer my question tho. "Why migration/seeding works if I cannot communicate with the database?"

Comment: I have this exact problem, so I'm switching between 'mysql' and '0.0.0.0' for DB_HOST. I have no idea how to fix this. By the way I am using Laravel 9.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you have `config/database.php` where all the setup for the connection is located. You also have a `.env` file in the root directory in your project (which everyone uses for timesaving). This contains variables that you can use for the entire project.

On a standard L5 project the MySql section of `config/database.php` looks like this:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
    'engine'    => null,
],
```

**Notice there is no port set!**

Although in my .env file I had set DB_PORT=33060. But that value (3306) was never read into the config/database.php.
So don't be a dumbass like myself and forget to check the database.php file.

**FIX**
Simply add 'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306), to your config/database.php and set that value in .env like this DB_PORT=3306

Comment: I tried it, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sail, try this command:

```
./vendor/bin/sail php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Works with default Docker & Laravel 9 installation from their official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x#laravel-and-docker